# main memory access time

Tags: caching, memory, architecture

I've recently begun to study cache memory. More specifically access time and hit ratio.

Now I gained a basic understanding such as effective access time, the formula for it etc. And so I began to ask questions of my own for a course in my university.

I got stuck in understanding this:

Assume that the cache access time is 2.5ns with a hit ratio of 0.95. Main memory uses a block transfer capability that has a first byte access time of 10ns and 5ns for each byte thereafter.

What is the access time when there is a cache miss? Assume that the cache waits until the line has been fetched from memory and then re-executes for a hit.

I dont understand how to get a fixed value for main memory, or more specifically a cache miss. I could use some help in UNDERSTANDING exactly what goes on. Thank you.